# How can I perform an ajax post to 2 php scripts at the same time?

Tags: ajax, post

I am using the following ajax function to post to a php script. (url_one.php)

How could I post the same data (myvar1, myvar2) to a second php script (ajaxURL2) at the same time ? Is there a way to do this ?

```
function ajax_function() {
    var myvar1 = $('myvar1').val();
    var myvar2 = $('.myvar2:checked').val();
    var ajaxURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/"+"url_one.php";
    var ajaxURL2 = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/"+"url_two.php"; // <-- to 2nd url simultaneously

    $.ajax({
    async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxURL,
    timeout : 8000,
        data: {functionname: 'my_php_function', arguments: [myvar1, myvar2]},
        success: function (data) {
        if( !('error' in data) ) {
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
        }},
    });
}
```

The ajax function is being called every five seconds using setTimeout .. (and never misses a beat..)

```
setTimeout(function(){
    ajax_function() ; 
    //... something here ?
}, 5000);
```

Should I be looking at this part, to post to more than one script at the same time? or be looking into a php side solution. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds simple; just can't seem to get my head around how to achieve it. I tried creating a php CRON job to do this all server side, but it kept missing the (5sec) intervals.. 10 seconds here, 30 seconds there etc. But this ajax way never missed the interval even over 12+ hours. Thanks.